# Spring security 403 error despite CSRF disabled

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've a set rules where it dictates which roles have access to which url. However, I'm getting 403 at urls where the role should have access to. Please refer below for the code and problem

Log

> org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is
> denied    at
> org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84)
> ~[spring-security-core-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233)
> ~[spring-security-core-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:123)
> ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]

Spring security configuration. Notice admin/** allows admin usage. I've logged in with admin, going to admin/welcome and it gives me 403.

```
  @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        
        // To access the h2 embedded database
        @Autowired
        DataSource dataSource;
        
        @Autowired
        Securityhandler successHandler;
        
        @Autowired
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
                throws Exception {
            auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                // To find logins in the h2 database
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select email, password, 'true' as enabled from User where email = ?")        
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select email, role " +
                                "from User " +
                                "where email =?");
            
        }
        
        
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/*", "/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    // formLogin redirect to login page
                    .and().formLogin()
                    .successHandler(successHandler);
                
            
            // In order to work with spring security csrf protection needs to be disabled
            http.csrf().disable();
            http.headers().frameOptions().disable();

        }
        
        // To encrypt password
        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }
    }
```

Admin user created with commandlinerunner so it is automatically created upon running the app. Notice the admin role at the end

```
@Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        // Creates new user upon running the app
        String password = securityConfig.passwordEncoder().encode("github");
        User user = new User("Billy", "billy", password, password, "sof@gmail.com", "ADMIN");
        userRep.save(user);
        System.out.println("Saved user:" + user);
    }
```

Entity class

```
@Entity
@ValidPassword
public class User {
    @Pattern(regexp="[a-zA-Z]+", message = "Enter letters only!")
    private String firstName;
    @Pattern(regexp="[a-zA-Z]+", message = "Enter letters only!")
    private String lastName;
    private String password;
    private String matchingPassword;
    private String passportNumber;
    private String address;
    private String phoneNumber;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @ValidEmail
    private String email;

    // Mark as primary key
    @Id
    // Will be auto generated
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String role;

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String password, String passportNumber, String address,
            String phoneNumber, String email, String role) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.password = password;
        this.passportNumber = passportNumber;
        this.address = address;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.email = email;
        this.role = role;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", password=" + password
                + ", matchingPassword=" + matchingPassword + ", passportNumber=" + passportNumber + ", address="
                + address + ", phoneNumber=" + phoneNumber + ", email=" + email + ", id=" + id + ", role=" + role + "]";
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getMatchingPassword() {
        return matchingPassword;
    }

    public void setMatchingPassword(String matchingPassword) {
        this.matchingPassword = matchingPassword;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getPassportNumber() {
        return passportNumber;
    }

    public void setPassportNumber(String passportNumber) {
        this.passportNumber = passportNumber;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User() {

    }

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String password, String matchingPassword, String email,
            String role) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.matchingPassword = matchingPassword;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
        this.role = role;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
```

Comment: Debug your authorities from `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities()` and check if maybe role names are different (prefixed with `ROLE_`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use hasAuthority/hasAnyAuthority instead of hasRole/hasAnyRole or add the prefix ROLE_ when you create the user as @matejko219 wrote in his comment.

Comment: hasAuthority worked. Can you explain the difference between hasrole and hasauthority?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#el-common-built-in

By default, hasRole add the prefix if the autority doesn't start by ROLE_